# Material-UI passing data between components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-props

This might look like a similar question but I'm unable to get the answer of it on Stackoverflow. 
I have two components - `A.js` and `B.js`

**A.js** 
(The below code is inside return() )

```
<Link to={{
   pathname: `${simulationId}/edit/${ruleName}`,
   search: createButtonQuery,
   previewFlag = true,
   }}>
    <IconButton color="primary" size="small">
         <PageviewOutlinedIcon/>
    </IconButton>
</Link>
```

**B.js** 
(The below code is inside return() )

```
<DialogTitle>{name ? 'Print true' : 'Print false'}</DialogTitle>
```

**Issue:** 
I want to test for `previewFlag` inside the `B.js`. I want to check when the `previewFlag` is true and `name` exists, 'Print true' should be returned by the `<DialogTitle>` 
I don't know how to use `previewFlag` inside `B.js` though.

Kindly note that `<PageViewOutlineIcon>` is part of material-ui here.
The both components aren't being imported by each other.

Comment: What is the relationship between these components? Parent/child? Siblings? How are you calling them within each other? Can you give us some more code?

Comment: The both components aren't being imported by each other. @JoelHager

Comment: If that's the case, then you'd either use a context, or you can implement your `preiewFlag` in a higher-order component, and pass it to both of them.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can make use of Context here @JoelHager I'm new to this concept

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer (cause it will give me the chance to show a *lot* of code. You could literally take it and adopt it for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a context, there are a few things you have to do:

1: Create a context file (I usually put mine in a contexts folder)

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = createContext()

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  function signOut() {
    return auth.signOut();
  }

  function signUp(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  function getUser() {
    return auth.currentUser
  }

  function isAdmin() {
    return auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
    .then((idTokenResult) => {
      if (!!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    })
  }

  function isEditor() {

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      setLoading(false)
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    getUser,
    login,
    signOut,
    signUp
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      { !loading && children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )

}
```

This is the file that can hold *whatever* you want to check for

Then, you need to put it in your App/_app (depending on how you're using react) as  in this case:

```
import '../styles/globals.scss'
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import { AuthProvider } from '../contexts/AuthContext'
import { CartProvider } from '../contexts/CartContext'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core'
import theme from '../styles/theme'


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  return(
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <CartProvider>
        <AuthProvider>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Header />
            <motion.div key={router.pathname} className="main">
              <Component { ...pageProps } />
              <Footer />
            </motion.div>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </CartProvider>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}
```

Then, in any component that you want access to those contexts, you can invoke it to use the values (or helper functions):

```
import { Alert, Grid, TextField, Button, makeStyles, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext'
import { useState } from 'react'

const theme = makeStyles({
  form: {
    width: '100vw',
    maxWidth: '400px',
    margin: 'auto',
    padding: '1rem',
  
    '& > div': {
      paddingBottom: '1rem'
    }
  }
})

export default function LoginForm() {
  const { login } = useAuth();
  const styles = theme()
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  })
  const [error, setError] = useState()
  const { googleLogin } = useAuth()

  function handleForm(e) {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  
  async function handleLogin() {
    await login(state.email, state.password)
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      setError(JSON.stringify(err))
    })
  }

  return(
    <Grid container className={styles.form} direction="column" alignContent="stretch" justify="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Typography variant="h3">Login</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        {error && <Alert severity="error" variant="filled" >{error}</Alert>}
          <TextField fullWidth name="email" label="Email" variant="outlined" onChange={handleForm}/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <TextField fullWidth name="password" type="password" label="Password" variant="outlined" onChange={handleForm} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary"fullWidth onClick={handleLogin}>Log In</Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

notice how I import the `useAuth` instance (which is just a context I've named that.  You can name it whatever) in my loginForm component, and then I can destructure out the values that I've exposed: `const { login } = useAuth()` Something like this: `const { value, helperFunction } = useAuth()` - assuming you're exporting a `value` and a function `helperFunction` from your context